# WinAPI concat two VOID buffers

Tags: c, winapi

```
do I need to manually do that ?
Does CopyMemory  accept shifting the destination ?
the following isn't working
```

```c
requestBuffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(fileBuffer) + sizeof(sendRequest) + 2, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    CopyMemory(requestBuffer,sendRequest, sizeof(sendRequest)); 
    CopyMemory((PVOID)(requestBuffer+sizeof(requestBuffer)),fileBuffer, sizeof(fileBuffer));
```

the last CopyMemory gives syntax error
Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type
I figured you can't dereference void , but any idea how to concat these two buffers

Comment: Please show the actual error message you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `requestBuffer` is a `void *`. You cannot use pointer arithmetic with `void` pointers. Try casting to `(PBYTE)` before adding:

```
CopyMemory((PVOID)((PBYTE)requestBuffer+sizeof(requestBuffer)), ...
```

Comment: I'm sure with the casting his problem is "solved", but isn't the `sizeof(requestBuffer)` in this case the size of a void pointer? its being allocated immediately prior and assigned to what appears to be a pointer, anyway. It makes me wonder if the OP ever discovered that should be the byte-length of his send-request, not the size of a pointer (if I'm reading this correctly). Finally, is the final PVOID cast even needed?

Comment: @WhozCraig: You're quite right, the `sizeof` seems wrong. Maybe it's supposed to be `sizeof(fileBuffer)`? Hard to say. As you say, the cast to `(PVOID)` isn't necessary, but I left it in there to maintain the connection with the original code.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes I discovered the sizeof() problem because it returned 4 :)